# how to copy a Select input and append it to a div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a Select input and it's name is "item" for example

```
<select name="item">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

i want to add a button that will copy this Select and removed Selected value if any and then append that copy to an a div called "all items".

how can i do that in Jquery? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to add a button that will **copy
>   this Select** and **removed Selected value**
>   if any and then **append that copy to an
>   a div** called "all items".

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   var copy = $('select[name=item]').clone();
   copy.children(':selected').removeAttr('selected'); // just unselect....
   // copy.children(':selected').remove() // if you want to remove the element...
   $('#div_all_items').append(copy); //Append.
})
```

Comment: that's works for a single click but it will not create another select if i click the button multiple times

Comment: are you sure it's not working? You can have a demo of that here http://jsbin.com/atiho/2 and it did sure work.

Answer (score 1):

Demo Online: http://jsbin.com/awuzo/edit

From what I understand, you want to remove what is selected, and then transfer the select element itself to a new location?

```
$(function(){
  // when we click our button
  $("#clickme").click(function(){
    // Move our SELECT and remove Selection value(s)
    $(":input[name='item']")
      .appendTo("#allitems")
      .children(":selected").remove(); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: @Reigel: What is the problem?

Comment: I was asking why input?... did I missed something?

Comment: @Reigel. Yes, you missed the colon :) `:input` from the jQuery site: "Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements"

Comment: Doug Neiner, the walking jQuery Documentation, to the rescue :) Hehe.

Comment: @Reigel: jQuery is a glorious framework - you'll find yourself learning something all the time. I do at least :) Largely at the correction of Mr. Neiner himself ;)